# Cookie is not stored in the brower, cross domain GET request

Tags: cookies, httpcookie

I have a domain (say cookiebaker.com) that provides files using GET requests. Whenever a request is made the cookiebaker server adds a set-cookie header to the file response.

Here is an example header (Max-Age is set for 1 month in the future):

```
set-cookie: cookie_name=cookie_value; Max-Age=2592000; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
```

Now when I call cookiebaker.com from a different domain (say munchies.com) I can see the set-cookie header in the GET response, but munchies.com does not store the cookie. I don't see the cookie in dev tools, and it is not uploaded in subsequent requests.

I am aware that I have to set the "withCredentials" flag to true when performing the GET request, but this didn't help in my case.

Here's my stripped down munchies.com code:

```
let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', "https://cookieBaker.com?param=value");
request.withCredentials = true; // Tell the browser to receive cookies
request.send();
```

Is there anything else that could block the cookie from being stored in the browser? These are all my access Control headers included in the GET response (localhost is the "real" name of munchies.com for my testing):

```
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-headers: Authorization, Content-Type
access-control-allow-methods: OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE
access-control-allow-origin: http://localhost
access-control-expose-headers: X-WP-Total, X-WP-TotalPages
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have explicitly set `SameSite=Lax` on the `cookiebaker.com` cookie, which will restrict it from being sent in a cross-site context, e.g. a `fetch()` originating from `munchies.com`.

For an explicit cross-site cookie, you should use `SameSite=None;Secure`. For more in-depth implementation detail, see https://web.dev/samesite-cookie-recipes

Comment: Woah, I thought it was the other way around! I read somewhere that lax let's cookies be sent through GET requests, but maybe I read it wrong. Thanks for  your help!

Comment: `GET` requests will include cookies on `SameSite=Lax` if they are a top level navigation to that same site.